# Focus Finder by Mac App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, focus, finder

I have a little Updater in my mac app, which automatically downloads a dmg-file with the latest version of the app. Now it also works to open this file, but how can I focus the Finder window? Otherwise the user wouldn't know that the dog-file was opened, because it is in the background.
This is the code I have for downloading and opening the file:

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                       [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:// ... .dmg"]];
    if([fileData writeToFile:@"/file.dmg" atomically:NO]) {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"file.dmg"];
        // Here I want to focus the new Finder window which has been opened by the code above
exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: What about `–openFile:withApplication:`? I don't work with OSX much, but I think that should do what you need.

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you! If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably use

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:myFile withApplication:@"Finder"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the method `activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:` from `NSWorkspace` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/activateFileViewerSelectingURLs%3a)).

You will find how to use it in my [showinfinder](http://github.com/gcerquant/showinfinder) project on GitHub.